# Is it OK to add multiple views to root view of an Activity?

Tags: android

It may sound foolish, but I actually can't find anything on it.
Is it ok to add multiple views to the root view of activity in Android?

So for example I could go like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
setContentView(gLView);
setContentView(otherView);
```

Or simply retrieve it as a view

```
FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout)this.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
layout.addView(view1);
layout.addView(view2);
layout.addView(view3);
layout.addView(view4);
```

It all seems to work on devices I test, but is it guaranteed to work on all of them?
Or should I artificially create single `FrameLayout` to add to root view and add everything to this `FrameLayout`?

**More experiments:**
1) if I don't use `setContentView` and print:

```
Log.d("Test", this.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).getClass().getName());
```

I get: android.widget.FrameLayout

2) If I set content view to for example `GLSurfaceView` and print the same `Log.d` 
It also prints android.widget.FrameLayout

3) And if I dont' use `setContentView` at all, and simply do

```
FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout)this.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
layout.addView(myView);
```

It attaches the view

So I assume that `android.R.id.content` returns not what you set by `setContentView` but the parent of what you set, or the actual root view in activity (which turns out is FrameLayout?)

And I am able to add multiple children to it this way, but question is:
**Am I allowed to do that?**

Comment: have setContentview more than once for the same activity is not a good idea. you can have a container in the layout and views to it.

Comment: without testing id assume that setContentView will replace previous views, while retrieving the FrameLayout and adding views to it, will keep em all.

Comment: true, it seems that setContentView replaces, but retrieving root view as layout allows to add multiple views. But question is, is it safe to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly fine to add multiple content `View`s at the root level. The content `View`s are simply added to a `FrameLayout` container, and it is best practice to simply use it for your layout if a `FrameLayout` is all you require for it, instead of adding an additional container layer.

If you are adding a new content `View`, then you should use the `addContentView()` method instead of `setContentView()`, which would cause the existing content to be replaced instead.

Also, it is possible to add multiple `View`s to the content container in XML layouts as well by using the [`<merge>` tag](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Merge), which would just replace the base `FrameLayout`.

Comment: `addContentView`, brilliant, that is the confirmation, that there could be multiple views.
Some how I missed that.
Thank you ;)

Comment: Answer my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76529993/add-view-to-android-rootview-application-without-permission

Answer (score 1):

Calling `setContentView` several times will simply replace whatever view you set before. So what you want to do is create a root view that contains the multiple views you want to add and set the root view to your Activity with `setContentView`. Your second example with the `FrameLayout` is a good approach.

Comment: I agree with you in principle.  However, note that the documentation suggests that although you can add multiple children to [`FrameLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) in general `FrameLayout` should be used to hold a single child `View`.

Comment: @JustinMuller You don't have to use `FrameLayout`. `LinearLayout` is usually the default root view people go with. I personally always go with `RelativeLayout`. It all depends on what you're trying to accomplish really.

Comment: But isn't `this.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);` would get you back the same root view, you set children to using `setContentView`? 
or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @ArtūrsSosins `setContentView` does not set a child, `setContentView` sets the root view that you will get back if you call `this.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);`

Comment: @Yasmani Llanes not exactly true, check my additions to the question

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is valid at some extent. but its nice practice to call the setcontentView() once in activity.

this is because it will be very easy to maintain the Activity life cycle and reduce the app crash due to layout leak.

I personally call the setcontentView() once. I define all the layout in single XML file. Afterwords I call `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` and `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` or `setVisibility(View.GONE)` to show or hide any particular layout containing my certain views.

**Edit**

Also its very easy to adjust the layout in XML because you can use simple drag and drop and If you are using `relativeLayout` then it will be very easy to place any view any where. but in Java code its some how difficult to place the views on your desired position

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Oh I know the good practices
but my purpose is a little different which is hard to explain and setting multiple views directly to root view without additional layout in xml or programmatically would save tons of time for me and hundreds of other developers

Comment: Good to know this :p I was just sharing my experience