# Add View to android rootView application without permission

Tags: android, android-windowmanager, rootview

> I want to add an overlay to the application rootView or BaseActivity without permission.

And it should be displayed on top of `BottomSheetDialog` or on top of **Copy Cut Paste** `ContextMenu` in `EditText`

I have tried multiple ways but didn't successed.

```
        val rootLayout = findViewById(android.R.id.content) as ViewGroup

        val viewToAdd = View.inflate(this,R.layout.fragment_maintenance,rootLayout)
        ///val viewToAdd = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maintenance,null)
        val params = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )
        viewToAdd.layoutParams = params
        ///params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM or Gravity.CENTER
        ///rootLayout.addView(viewToAdd)
        ///val rootLayout = window.decorView.rootView
        //val rootLayout = window.decorView.findViewById<ViewGroup>(android.R.id.content)
        ///View.inflate(this, R.layout.fragment_maintenance, rootLayout)
```

And can we add any view using WindowManager without permission.